# Connect Gazebo SDF model to ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, since I'm a newbie in ROS and Gazebo I'm having trouble to find some tutorial or someone who could explain how to connect a robot SDF model to ROS so that I could acquire sensor data. Is there any tutorial or something that could give me a hint or some plugin which can connect a SDF model to ROS like a URDF model? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258625/connect-gazebo-sdf-model-to-ros/) by [sirsomething](https://answers.ros.org/users/28660/sirsomething/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A SDF model can only be used inside gazebo. Rviz and other ROS related software uses only URDF.
However you can add to your URDF gazebo tags that allow your URDF model to be deployed inside gazebo because this simulator converts, under the hood, your URDF model to an SDF model.

---

Originally posted by [agbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29369/agbj/) with karma: 83 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1